# how to measure polygon perimeter / Distance in openlayers 3?

Tags: polygon, openlayers, distance, measurements

i am using openlayers 3 measurement tool for measuring line lengths and polygons areas, and this example worked for me: http://www.rhone-mediterranee.eaufrance.fr/milieux-aquatiques/poissons/js/openlayers-v3.19.1/examples/measure.html ,
but i want to add something like getlenght or get perimeter for the polygon so when i draw a polygon i get the area and the perimter also ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just ask for the perimeter of the outer `linearring` of your polygon. To do so within the example you provide and on the `draw.on('drawstart',` listener function change this block of code:

```
if (geom instanceof ol.geom.Polygon) {
output = formatArea(geom);
tooltipCoord = geom.getInteriorPoint().getCoordinates();
}
```

To this:

```
if (geom instanceof ol.geom.Polygon) {
output = formatArea(geom) +" " + formatLength(new ol.geom.LineString(geom.getLinearRing(0).getCoordinates()));
tooltipCoord = geom.getInteriorPoint().getCoordinates();
}
```

Here is a fiddle --> https://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/utakLt5j/

Comment: no probms. glad to help